# Script that reads rows and columns in a sheet and returns strings with frequency of occurrence

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

first time caller!

I have a single column that contains comma separated names (lots of names) -- I am trying to find a script that can read the comma separated string entries in cell and give me a frequency count of each unique word. For example,

Dave
Jack
Anita, Peter
Peter
Kate, Noor
Noor
Peter
Peter, Dave

The expected output will be

Anita - 1
Dave - 2
Jack - 1
Kate - 1
Noor - 2
Peter - 4

Looking for any help. I know nothing about apps script and I am a novice sheets user too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a cell containing a number of words. Some words are separated by spaces and some words are separated by spaces AND commas; there appears to be no pattern for the occurrence of spaces and commas.

You want to count the occurrences of the unique words, then display the result in a single cell. The format of the cell is the word, dash, count, space; and repeat.

There are likely to be many possible solutions to your question. Please consider this answer as one possible solution.

---

Assume your data is in Cell B1, enter this formula in Cell B2:

`=join(" ",ARRAYFORMULA(query({query({transpose(split(substitute(B1,",","")," ",true,true))},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by Col1 asc label count(Col1) ''",),query({transpose(split(substitute(B1,",","")," ",true,true))},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by Col1 asc label count(Col1) ''",)}, "select Col1 where Col1 = Col3")&"-"&query({query({transpose(split(substitute(B1,",","")," ",true,true))},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by Col1 asc label count(Col1) ''",),query({transpose(split(substitute(B1,",","")," ",true,true))},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by Col1 asc label count(Col1) ''",)}, "select Col2 where Col1 = Col3")))`

---

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Explanation:**

- `substitute(B1,",","")`: removes any commas
- `split(substitute(B1,",","")," ",true,true)`: separate the words (delimiter=one space).
- `transpose(split(substitute(B1,",","")," ",true,true))`: List in a column
- `query({transpose(split(substitute(B1,",","")," ",true,true))},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by Col1 asc label count(Col1) ''",)`: create a list of unique names and the count of occurances, sorted in alphabetical order.
- `query({<<query>>=Col1,<<query>>=Col1 and Count(Col1), "select Col1"}&"-"&query({<<query>>=Col1,<<query>>=Col1 and Count(Col1),"select count(Col1)"})`: combine the Name (Col1), a dash, and the Count (count(Col1)). Note: output = only one row
- `Arrayformula(<<query>>)`: performs the preceeding query for all rows
- `join(" ",Arrayformula(<<query>>))`: converts the column to a single cell; delimited = one space.